# SQL: How do I Get Columns from Joined Tables

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have this query, which gives the initial result shown. My end goal is to solve for the following:

For every pair of students who both like each other, return the name and grade of both students

Here is the initial query I wrote, and the ID pairs that match:

```
select L1.ID1, L1. ID2
from Likes L1, Likes L2
where L1.ID1 = L2.ID2 and L2.ID1 = L1.ID2 and L1.ID1 > L1.ID2
```

My Query Result:

```
1709 1689
1934 1501
```

The problem I am having is returning the name and grade of each of these IDs, where the IDs would be in this table:

Students (ID, name, grade)

So, how do I get to the following:

**Expected Query Result:**

```
name1 grade1 name2 grade2
name1 grade1 name2 grade2
```

Where name and grade come from the Students table, based on the IDs from the first query?

Comment: Pl show how does your table look with data?

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : using old-style JOINs](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins) - that old-style *comma-separated list of tables* style was discontinued with the ANSI-**92** SQL Standard (**20 years** ago!).

Answer (score 0):

```
Select L1.name as name1, L1.grade as grade1, L2.name as name2, L2.grade as gade2 from ...
```

Answer (score 0):

Two join on students should do the trick

```
SELECT 
l1.ID1, l1.ID2
s1.name as name1, s1.grade as grade1, 
s2.name as name2, s2.grade as grade2
FROM Likes l1
INNER JOIN Likes l2 ON l1.ID1 = l2.ID2 and l2.ID1 = l1.ID2
INNER JOIN students s1 on s1.ID = l1.ID1
INNER JOIN students s2 on s2.ID = l1.ID2
WHERE l1.ID1 > l1.ID2
```